# Doctrine/Symfony2 - DELETE FROM table WHERE field = "test"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I can't believe I can't seem to find this anywhere (without just forcing the entire SQL in). Docs talk about adding, searching, updating and removing an entity, but I just can't see how to do what this would be in pure SQL:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE field = "test"
```

I'm guessing this just adds and updates, so I can't use this:

```
$product = new Product();

// etc.

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();
```

and I don't think the 'remove' option would do it either:

```
$em->remove($product);
$em->flush();
```

So, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search for the entity and remove it.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Product');

/** @var $product Product */
$product = $repository->findOneBy(array('field' => 'test'));
$em->remove($product);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: If I use findBy to get all records rather than just findByOne then there is an error saying "EntityManager#remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, array given." - surely I don't need to foreach over $product and remove each one. This seems a very long-winded way to do it. Is it the best way?

Comment: Indeed. If you use `findBy` you have to foreach over the results.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Doesn't seem great to me, but it does seem the right way.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a DQL query like this :

```
$query = $repository->createQuery('DELETE FROM entity e WHERE e.id = :id');
$query->setParameter('id', $id);
$query->execute();
```